# Adding figure caption to figure inside tabPanel in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How do I properly add a figure text to a figure placed inside a tabPanel?
I have tried the following, but the text does not align within the tabPanel box.

```r
tabBox(
  tabPanel(
    "name",
    fluidRow(
      plotlyOutput("plot", width = "100%", height = "65vh")
    ),
    fluidRow(
      HTML("This is the caption text.")
    )
  )
)
```

Is there another way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only seeing a piece of your code, it's really hard to tell what you're seeing or what you'd like changed. However, from the experimenting I did, the `fluidRow`'s within the the `tabPanel` seemed to cause both the plot and text to render outside of the `tabPanel`. Removing both instances of `fluidRow` fixed it for me.

```r
ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
    shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(title = "title"),
    shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(),
    shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
        shinydashboard::tabBox(
            title = "title",
            shiny::tabPanel(
                "name",
                plotly::plotlyOutput("plot", width = "100%", height = "65vh"),
                shiny::tags$p("This is the caption text.")
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- plotly::renderPlotly({
        plotly::plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
    })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: ex]